# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, casting

There is an issue with a new project, that uses the same Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc etc version as another project that does the exact same thing, but doesn't cause a cast issue.

[This is an example of the project that doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH9Nq.png)

[And this an example of the expected behaviour from a working service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjZNk.png)

- The route exists, but it is invoking HandleUnknownAction because the required parameters weren't supplied, in this case the required parameter is "counterName"

If feel as if there is a simple explanation to this.

Here is the block of code that the cast is in:

```cs
if (Policy == VerbPolicy.AfterChecks)
{
    var descriptor = (TaskAsyncActionDescriptor)filterContext.ActionDescriptor;

    if (descriptor != null)
    {
        var parameters = descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            var argument = filterContext.ActionParameters[parameter.Name];

            if (!EvaluateValidationAttributes(parameter, argument, filterContext))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any more information required, please ask.

Comment: Hmm, I beleive I have solved the issue, the action that works is already a `System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor`, and the action is an Async method, unlike the other one.

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea what to cast it to, or what to change if I was just to use the raw System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor

Comment: [The expected response when making the action return Task.CompletedTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvn8n.png)